# Is it possible to extract all Images or Tables or any other object from a word document and add them to an appendix?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

While writing a report, I was asked to extract all the images in the text to a separate appendix. The document is not too long, ~100 pages, but there are many figures. How can I do this using MS Word 2013 automatically?

Note that I do not want to extract a table of figures, I just want to extract all the images with their captions as a separate appendix.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there would be a standard way for that. You'll need to use a macro for it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thanks for the comment. I am completely new to Macros. Where can I begin to learn?

Comment: e.g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff604039(v=office.14).aspx), or just google for `word vba tutorial`

Comment: I've found a workaround, but don't have time to write a complete answer, short method: 1: save a copy of your document. 2. Change font to be the same across the whole document (e.g. times). 3. replace all pictures (`^g`) to picture + special text (e.g. `^&##`). 4. replace all caption + picture to a new font (e.g. `figure?{1,100}##`) 5. find and select all text with the original font. Delete them (press `Del`)